# Error in installing pycrypto-2.3 on fedora 15

Tags: python, pycrypto

Hi i am trying to install pycrypto-2.3 from [here](http://mac.softpedia.com/progDownload/PyCrypto-Download-45106.html)

I downloaded and run the following command

```
cd pycrypto-2.3/

python setup.py install
```

I am getting the following error,

```
running install
running build
running build_py
creating build
creating build/lib.linux-x86_64-2.7
creating build/lib.linux-x86_64-2.7/Crypto
copying lib/Crypto/pct_warnings.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-2.7/Crypto
copying lib/Crypto/__init__.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-2.7/Crypto
creating build/lib.linux-x86_64-2.7/Crypto/Hash
copying lib/Crypto/Hash/SHA.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-2.7/Crypto/Hash
copying lib/Crypto/Hash/__init__.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-2.7/Crypto/Hash
copying lib/Crypto/Hash/MD5.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-2.7/Crypto/Hash
copying lib/Crypto/Hash/RIPEMD.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-2.7/Crypto/Hash
copying lib/Crypto/Hash/HMAC.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-2.7/Crypto/Hash
creating build/lib.linux-x86_64-2.7/Crypto/Cipher
copying lib/Crypto/Cipher/__init__.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-2.7/Crypto/Cipher
creating build/lib.linux-x86_64-2.7/Crypto/Util
copying lib/Crypto/Util/_number_new.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-2.7/Crypto/Util
copying lib/Crypto/Util/__init__.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-2.7/Crypto/Util
copying lib/Crypto/Util/winrandom.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-2.7/Crypto/Util
copying lib/Crypto/Util/python_compat.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-2.7/Crypto/Util
copying lib/Crypto/Util/RFC1751.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-2.7/Crypto/Util
copying lib/Crypto/Util/asn1.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-2.7/Crypto/Util
copying lib/Crypto/Util/randpool.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-2.7/Crypto/Util
copying lib/Crypto/Util/Counter.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-2.7/Crypto/Util
copying lib/Crypto/Util/number.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-2.7/Crypto/Util
creating build/lib.linux-x86_64-2.7/Crypto/Random
copying lib/Crypto/Random/_UserFriendlyRNG.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-2.7/Crypto/Random
copying lib/Crypto/Random/__init__.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-2.7/Crypto/Random
copying lib/Crypto/Random/random.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-2.7/Crypto/Random
creating build/lib.linux-x86_64-2.7/Crypto/Random/Fortuna
copying lib/Crypto/Random/Fortuna/__init__.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-2.7/Crypto/Random/Fortuna
copying lib/Crypto/Random/Fortuna/FortunaAccumulator.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-2.7/Crypto/Random/Fortuna
copying lib/Crypto/Random/Fortuna/FortunaGenerator.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-2.7/Crypto/Random/Fortuna
copying lib/Crypto/Random/Fortuna/SHAd256.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-2.7/Crypto/Random/Fortuna
creating build/lib.linux-x86_64-2.7/Crypto/Random/OSRNG
copying lib/Crypto/Random/OSRNG/rng_base.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-2.7/Crypto/Random/OSRNG
copying lib/Crypto/Random/OSRNG/__init__.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-2.7/Crypto/Random/OSRNG
copying lib/Crypto/Random/OSRNG/posix.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-2.7/Crypto/Random/OSRNG
copying lib/Crypto/Random/OSRNG/fallback.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-2.7/Crypto/Random/OSRNG
copying lib/Crypto/Random/OSRNG/nt.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-2.7/Crypto/Random/OSRNG
creating build/lib.linux-x86_64-2.7/Crypto/SelfTest
copying lib/Crypto/SelfTest/st_common.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-2.7/Crypto/SelfTest
copying lib/Crypto/SelfTest/__init__.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-2.7/Crypto/SelfTest
creating build/lib.linux-x86_64-2.7/Crypto/SelfTest/Cipher
copying lib/Crypto/SelfTest/Cipher/test_AES.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-2.7/Crypto/SelfTest/Cipher
copying lib/Crypto/SelfTest/Cipher/test_DES3.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-2.7/Crypto/SelfTest/Cipher
copying lib/Crypto/SelfTest/Cipher/__init__.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-2.7/Crypto/SelfTest/Cipher
copying lib/Crypto/SelfTest/Cipher/common.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-2.7/Crypto/SelfTest/Cipher
copying lib/Crypto/SelfTest/Cipher/test_ARC2.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-2.7/Crypto/SelfTest/Cipher
copying lib/Crypto/SelfTest/Cipher/test_Blowfish.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-2.7/Crypto/SelfTest/Cipher
copying lib/Crypto/SelfTest/Cipher/test_DES.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-2.7/Crypto/SelfTest/Cipher
copying lib/Crypto/SelfTest/Cipher/test_ARC4.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-2.7/Crypto/SelfTest/Cipher
copying lib/Crypto/SelfTest/Cipher/test_CAST.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-2.7/Crypto/SelfTest/Cipher
copying lib/Crypto/SelfTest/Cipher/test_XOR.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-2.7/Crypto/SelfTest/Cipher
creating build/lib.linux-x86_64-2.7/Crypto/SelfTest/Hash
copying lib/Crypto/SelfTest/Hash/test_MD5.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-2.7/Crypto/SelfTest/Hash
copying lib/Crypto/SelfTest/Hash/test_SHA.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-2.7/Crypto/SelfTest/Hash
copying lib/Crypto/SelfTest/Hash/__init__.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-2.7/Crypto/SelfTest/Hash
copying lib/Crypto/SelfTest/Hash/common.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-2.7/Crypto/SelfTest/Hash
copying lib/Crypto/SelfTest/Hash/test_HMAC.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-2.7/Crypto/SelfTest/Hash
copying lib/Crypto/SelfTest/Hash/test_MD2.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-2.7/Crypto/SelfTest/Hash
copying lib/Crypto/SelfTest/Hash/test_MD4.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-2.7/Crypto/SelfTest/Hash
copying lib/Crypto/SelfTest/Hash/test_SHA256.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-2.7/Crypto/SelfTest/Hash
copying lib/Crypto/SelfTest/Hash/test_RIPEMD.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-2.7/Crypto/SelfTest/Hash
creating build/lib.linux-x86_64-2.7/Crypto/SelfTest/Protocol
copying lib/Crypto/SelfTest/Protocol/__init__.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-2.7/Crypto/SelfTest/Protocol
copying lib/Crypto/SelfTest/Protocol/test_rfc1751.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-2.7/Crypto/SelfTest/Protocol
copying lib/Crypto/SelfTest/Protocol/test_chaffing.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-2.7/Crypto/SelfTest/Protocol
creating build/lib.linux-x86_64-2.7/Crypto/SelfTest/PublicKey
copying lib/Crypto/SelfTest/PublicKey/__init__.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-2.7/Crypto/SelfTest/PublicKey
copying lib/Crypto/SelfTest/PublicKey/test_DSA.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-2.7/Crypto/SelfTest/PublicKey
copying lib/Crypto/SelfTest/PublicKey/test_importKey.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-2.7/Crypto/SelfTest/PublicKey
copying lib/Crypto/SelfTest/PublicKey/test_RSA.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-2.7/Crypto/SelfTest/PublicKey
creating build/lib.linux-x86_64-2.7/Crypto/SelfTest/Random
copying lib/Crypto/SelfTest/Random/__init__.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-2.7/Crypto/SelfTest/Random
copying lib/Crypto/SelfTest/Random/test_rpoolcompat.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-2.7/Crypto/SelfTest/Random
copying lib/Crypto/SelfTest/Random/test_random.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-2.7/Crypto/SelfTest/Random
creating build/lib.linux-x86_64-2.7/Crypto/SelfTest/Random/Fortuna
copying lib/Crypto/SelfTest/Random/Fortuna/__init__.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-2.7/Crypto/SelfTest/Random/Fortuna
copying lib/Crypto/SelfTest/Random/Fortuna/test_SHAd256.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-2.7/Crypto/SelfTest/Random/Fortuna
copying lib/Crypto/SelfTest/Random/Fortuna/test_FortunaGenerator.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-2.7/Crypto/SelfTest/Random/Fortuna
copying lib/Crypto/SelfTest/Random/Fortuna/test_FortunaAccumulator.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-2.7/Crypto/SelfTest/Random/Fortuna
creating build/lib.linux-x86_64-2.7/Crypto/SelfTest/Random/OSRNG
copying lib/Crypto/SelfTest/Random/OSRNG/__init__.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-2.7/Crypto/SelfTest/Random/OSRNG
copying lib/Crypto/SelfTest/Random/OSRNG/test_posix.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-2.7/Crypto/SelfTest/Random/OSRNG
copying lib/Crypto/SelfTest/Random/OSRNG/test_winrandom.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-2.7/Crypto/SelfTest/Random/OSRNG
copying lib/Crypto/SelfTest/Random/OSRNG/test_generic.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-2.7/Crypto/SelfTest/Random/OSRNG
copying lib/Crypto/SelfTest/Random/OSRNG/test_fallback.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-2.7/Crypto/SelfTest/Random/OSRNG
copying lib/Crypto/SelfTest/Random/OSRNG/test_nt.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-2.7/Crypto/SelfTest/Random/OSRNG
creating build/lib.linux-x86_64-2.7/Crypto/SelfTest/Util
copying lib/Crypto/SelfTest/Util/test_asn1.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-2.7/Crypto/SelfTest/Util
copying lib/Crypto/SelfTest/Util/__init__.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-2.7/Crypto/SelfTest/Util
copying lib/Crypto/SelfTest/Util/test_winrandom.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-2.7/Crypto/SelfTest/Util
copying lib/Crypto/SelfTest/Util/test_Counter.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-2.7/Crypto/SelfTest/Util
copying lib/Crypto/SelfTest/Util/test_number.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-2.7/Crypto/SelfTest/Util
creating build/lib.linux-x86_64-2.7/Crypto/Protocol
copying lib/Crypto/Protocol/AllOrNothing.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-2.7/Crypto/Protocol
copying lib/Crypto/Protocol/__init__.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-2.7/Crypto/Protocol
copying lib/Crypto/Protocol/Chaffing.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-2.7/Crypto/Protocol
creating build/lib.linux-x86_64-2.7/Crypto/PublicKey
copying lib/Crypto/PublicKey/__init__.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-2.7/Crypto/PublicKey
copying lib/Crypto/PublicKey/RSA.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-2.7/Crypto/PublicKey
copying lib/Crypto/PublicKey/DSA.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-2.7/Crypto/PublicKey
copying lib/Crypto/PublicKey/_slowmath.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-2.7/Crypto/PublicKey
copying lib/Crypto/PublicKey/_DSA.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-2.7/Crypto/PublicKey
copying lib/Crypto/PublicKey/qNEW.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-2.7/Crypto/PublicKey
copying lib/Crypto/PublicKey/_RSA.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-2.7/Crypto/PublicKey
copying lib/Crypto/PublicKey/pubkey.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-2.7/Crypto/PublicKey
copying lib/Crypto/PublicKey/ElGamal.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-2.7/Crypto/PublicKey
running build_ext
warning: GMP library not found; Not building Crypto.PublicKey._fastmath.
building 'Crypto.Hash.MD2' extension
creating build/temp.linux-x86_64-2.7
creating build/temp.linux-x86_64-2.7/src
gcc -pthread -fno-strict-aliasing -pipe -Wall -Wp,-D_FORTIFY_SOURCE=2 -fexceptions -fstack-protector --param=ssp-buffer-size=4 -m64 -mtune=generic -D_GNU_SOURCE -fPIC -fwrapv -pipe -Wall -Wp,-D_FORTIFY_SOURCE=2 -fexceptions -fstack-protector --param=ssp-buffer-size=4 -m64 -mtune=generic -D_GNU_SOURCE -fPIC -fwrapv -fPIC -std=c99 -O3 -fomit-frame-pointer -Isrc/ -I/usr/include/python2.7 -c src/MD2.c -o build/temp.linux-x86_64-2.7/src/MD2.o
src/MD2.c:31:20: fatal error: Python.h: No such file or directory
compilation terminated.
error: command 'gcc' failed with exit status 1
```

can anyone please let me know how to solve this and install pycrypto-2.3 successfully on my machine.

Answer (score 6):

PyCrypto is called python-crypto in Fedora, and can be installed with:

```
yum install python-crypto
```

Comment: The package "python-crypto" doesn't seem to exist anymore.

Answer (score 2):

It's always worth reading the documentation first. I'll quote from pycrypto's README:

> Red Hat users often run into this because they don't have the
>   python2-devel RPM installed. The fix is to simply install the
>   requisite RPM.

***edit*** I'll add, don't get your software from a website like softpedia (especially not crypto software!). Get it from the [pycrypto website](https://www.dlitz.net/software/pycrypto/) and verify the signature and file hash.

Comment: Thanks for ur answer, if u don't mind i want to know that whether it is recommended to do this using rpm or whether there is any other wya to achieve the same.

Comment: Thanks for u r suggestion thats really helpful, actually my doubt is, i heared some how that installing the packages by downloading rpm packages from here "http://rpm.pbone.net/index.php3/stat/4/idpl/15935975/dir/fedora_15/com/python-devel-2.7.1-7.fc15.x86_64.rpm.html" is not a right approach and not recommended, so please can u let me know is there any otherway to install this python-devel package

Answer (score 1):

To solve this, you only need to install python-devel beforehand.
But if you are using Fedora-23 like me, you may face another problem before this one. So you need to install one more package.

```
sudo dnf install redhat-rpm-config python-devel
```

Answer (score 0):

In some versions of Fedora it's necessary to install the following package:
`dnf install deluge`.